# Help understanding the solutions and answers to this inequalities question

Tags: inequality

Find the set of solutions that satisfy

$\dfrac{3}{x+3}>\dfrac{x-4}{x}$

So I began by multiplying out to get

$3x>x^2-x-12$

$x^2-4x-12=0$, which gives $x=-2$ and $x=6$.

So these two x-values would be the two x-coordinates where the line $3x$ and the curve $x^2-x-12$ intersect. Hence, by doing a simple sketch of the two it can be seen that the inequality representing $3x>x^2-x-12$ is $-2<x<6$, as it is between these two x-coordinates that $3x$ is above the curve.

Since $3x>x^2-x-12$ is the same as $\dfrac{3}{x+3}>\dfrac{x-4}{x}$, would it not follow that $-2<x<-6$ satisfies both, and is therefore the answer?

The mark scheme says that x=-2 and x=6 are critical values, which I found. However, they didn't get the same answer as me.

The mark scheme says:

> Other critical values: $x=-3, x=0$.
>   Therefore $-3<x<-2$ and $0<x<-6$.

Can someone answer these questions:

How did they get the other two critical values?
How do their final inequalities satisfy the original inequality?
Why is mine wrong? It seems perfectly credible to me.

Comment: At the very start, you assumed the factors you multiplied by to clear the denominator were all positive. In the event any one factor, or all three, is/are negative, you need to change the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said "*So I began by multiplying out to get...*" This isn't correct unless you assume that $x$ and $x+3$ are positive! To solve this inequality:
$$\dfrac{3}{x+3}>\dfrac{x-4}{x}\iff \dfrac{3}{x+3}-\dfrac{x-4}{x}>0\iff\frac{-x^2-4x+12}{x(x+3)}>0$$

Now draw a signs table and find the intervals on which this fraction is positive.

**Edit**

[image]